# Prove this function is only continuous at x=0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

6.24 references a proposition from our lecture in which we were shown that Q and R\Q are dense in R. I am aware there are some statements missing, eg: Thus ... is discontinuous at ... and thus ... is only continuous at ... (This was just a rough draft). Would really appreciate if you could check if this is correct (Case 1 gave me the most grief - pretty sure it is wrong).

Thanks for any help, Ethan.

Comment: You will find it helps if you spend a bit of time learning the rudiments of TeX. For example, if you put dollars signs around "6.24 \implies \exists x \in \mathbb{Q}" you get "$6.24 \implies \exists x \in \mathbb{Q}$." The hardest thing to typeset in your "\epsilon \delta" proof here is the two-case definition of your function $f(x)$ with one formula for $x$ in "\mathbb{Q}" and another for $x$ in "\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}," but if you do your best there someone can come along and fix it, and then you'll be able to see how to do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Put $\delta = \varepsilon$. [By density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$], there exists $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$. Then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x)| \leq |x| < \delta = \varepsilon$.

This has all of the ingredients of the correct solution but has made some quantifier errors. You want to show that **for all** $x$ satisfying $|x - x_0| < \delta$, the inequality $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ holds. If $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then since $x_0 = 0$, this is the same as $|x| < \delta$ (as you pointed out). If $x$ is irrational, then $|f(x)| \leq |x|$; otherwsise, $|f(x)| = |x|$. In any case, $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x)| \leq |x| < \delta$, so $\delta = \varepsilon$ is the right choice.

Comment: Why is the statement about density in square brackets? (is it some sort of proof notation?). Other than that this makes perfect sense, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Because you said that 6.24 is a proposition on that point. Is that not correct?

Comment: Ah, so you're just replacing the number with something more meaningful? In that case I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that f is continuous at x= a if and only if, for any sequence $\{x_i\}$ that converges to a, $\{f(x_i)\}$ converges to f(a)?  That, together with the fact that, given any a, there exist a sequence of rational numbers that converges to a as well as a sequence of irrational numbers that converges to a, appears to be the simplest way to do this.

If a is irrational then f(a)= 0.  But there exist a sequence of **rational numbers**, $\{x_i\}$, that converge to a. Then $\{f(x_i\}= \{x_i\}$ converges to a, not 0.  Therefore f is not continuous at any irrational number.

If a is rational but non-zero then f(a)= a.  But there exist a sequence of **irrational numbers**, $\{x_i\}$, that converges to a.  Then $\{f(x_i)\}= \{0\}$ converges to 0, not a.  Therefore, f is not continuous at any non-zero rational number.

Finally suppose a= 0.  Then f(a)= f(0)= 0.  Take any sequence, $\{x_i\}$, that converges to 0.  That sequence **may** include irrational numbers but since f of any irrational number is 0, we can ignore them. 
 The remaining is a sequence of rational numbers, $\{x_i\}$, that converges to 0.  Then $\{f(x_i)\}= \{x_i\}$ which converges to 0. Therefore f **is** continuous at 0.